# When  an abelian category has enough flat objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory

For a coalgebra C over a field K, the category C-Comod of left C-comodules
is an example of locally finitely presented Grothendieck category. For this type of
categories a notion of flat object exists due to Stenström [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186936890064)

It is known that every module has a flat cover by [this paper](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/33/4/385.short)

We also  know that  each locally finitely presented Grothendieck category has enough flat objects by [the paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810001350)

More generally, When  an abelian category has enough flat objects? Let $A$ be an abelian category with enough flat objects, does each object in $A$ has a flat cover?

Comment: What is the definition of a flat object in an abelian category ?

Comment: In the case of a module category the existence of flat precovers (or with your terminology of enough flat objects) is sufficient for deriving the existence of flat covers. More generally the same is true for every precovering class which is closed under direct colimits. The same argument works for Grothendieck categories, giving a partial answer to the last question. For the rest, I think the paper by Rump whose link gave you already should offer a good answer. 

Comment: Can we define flat objects in any abelian category as follows: an
object $M$ is flat if for every diagram $$ \xymatrix{
K  \ar[r] & M \ar[d] &  \\
A \ar[r] & B \ar[r] & 0}
$$


with exact sequence  $A \rightarrow  B \rightarrow  0$
and $K$ finitely presented can be completed by a map $K\rightarrow
A$   to be a commutative diagram

Comment: Is there an abelian category which has enough flat objects but no projective objects?

Comment: Yes, the category of quasicoherent sheaves over a scheme has enough flat sheaves, but often (when the scheme is non-affine) no nonzero projective.

Comment: thanks a lot George C. Modoi.  I find a new paper[Locally finitely presented categories with no flat objects 
][1]
[1]: http://arxiv.org/list/math.CT/recent
 which gives some examples 

Comment: @Aimin It seems to me that George has done a good job answering your second question. I doubt anyone has characterized abelian categories with enough flat objects. Has anyone even done this for having enough projectives? Enough injectives? Perhaps if you could tell us what application you have in mind we could figure out if there are enough flat objects in that particular setting.

Comment: @GeorgeC.Modoi Do you assert that if $QCoh(X)$ has enough projectives, then $X$ is affine? If so, I'd love to hear more about this -- in particular, it would answer one form of my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290147/is-every-nice-abelian-category-with-enough-projectives-an-additive-presheaf-ca/).