# Locally noetherian (AB4*) Grothendieck categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let A be a Grothendieck category satisfying (AB4*) (that is, with exact products).

Assuming that, moreover, A is locally noetherian, must this category have enough small projective objects (so, to be equivalent to a category of additive functors from a small preadditive category to abelian groups)?

If it is, may the "locally noetherian" assumption be relaxed into "locally finitely presented", or even "locally finitely generated" of (AB6)?

Thanks!

Comment: In this paper: https://www.academia.edu/31035256/Gabriel_Popescu_type_theorems_and_applications one finds the Theorem that, for a locally finite Grothendieck category, (AB4*) is equivalent to having enough projectives. It is a first step...

Comment: If you look at the edit history to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/290308/2362) you'll see I spent some time trying to prove this a few years ago, without success.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I was not aware of your post. So, the question seems really hard.

Comment: You're probably already aware, but for context I find [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0024610705022416) of Roos very relevant. In particular, there is Cor 1.4 which says that for a Grothendieck category, $AB4^\ast$ is equivalent to the existence of projective effacements, and the results of Section 4, where Roos gives examples of nonzero Grothendieck categories satisfying $AB4^\ast$ and $AB6$ which have no nonzero projectives. Thus certainly _some_ condition is needed.

Comment: Oh, of course you're aware -- you referenced this paper in a comment on the page I linked to!

Comment: Indeed Roos's paper contains a lot of very interesting results and couter-examples. But I guess that all the counter-examples are far from being locally noetherian... It answers my last question (with only (AB6)) anyway. Even with "locally finitely generated", it is not so clear for me what happens.